# How to share Parent component model with multiple child components In Angular?

Tags: angular

I know There are different ways to share your parent component model with child components using,

1. Input/Output
2. Shared Services
3. Ngrx store.

I've a huge page to get user input, with very big model binded to parent component. As to maintain the code I've moved code accordingly to child component. 
Now I want to append data from all child components to single model.

Basically I'm looking for the way to share single model across multiple child components. I could use anyone of the above but each option has it's own cost.

I'm looking to simply read the data from child components and bind it to the single model while exiting from each component.

Comment: Looking for an answer too, how did you solve it ?